# What are the key documents involved in a software project?

Tags: agile, product-management, documentation

From project proposal to Delivery - in the software development,

1. Which all documents are involved and
2. What is the order?

While using Agile development, including SRS, DB structure, source code documentation and test cases, what are the documents should I write while creating a software project to the delivery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does documentation like business and software requirement spec docs fit in an agile project?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/25875/where-does-documentation-like-business-and-software-requirement-spec-docs-fit-in)

Answer (score 1):

Having a productive development team and getting the right kind of engagement with stakeholders are what matter. If those are in place then the team can decide for themselves what documentation is useful. A single answer is not going to suit all projects and the same documentation won't necessarily be appropriate for every situation on a given project.

A checklist of documentation can even be seen as demotivating since a good team will want to focus on delivering software rather than satisfying a quota of documents.

Comment: I needed the list of documents to be made during a software project! For example
1. Project proposal
2. SDLC
3. ER diagram and so on,
with the technical names

Comment: @ShanMarshBubashan: Why do you need a list of documents to be made during a software project? And what do you intend to do with it if you get it? Is this for work or a school assignment?

Comment: @Bogdan : More over this a project for final year in  High school, Got an outline of documents do to be made, though i need to know the set of documents to be made while creating a project for a commercial reason or else for a to make in a startup company.

Comment: This is close to, if not the, correct answer, @ShanMarshBubashan. There are no "list of documents to be made during a software project". Ultimately, a software project requires the production of software, not documents. Different environments may require different pieces of supporting data, which may or may not be captured in documents. "Artifacts" is one of the more current terms, since they may be electronic records or exports as well. But these vary widely based on the environment and team.

Comment: @ThomasOwens thanks for the comment, so what type of document does a project proposal, SRS document, Test case report, Project final report comes in? and is there any other artifacts i missed?? if so can you update it please